# Softkeybord case using libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've using a libgdx TextField to receive a name from the user for a highscores table, and I'd like to set up the soft keyboard or the TextField so that the first character typed is capitalised. Is there an easy way to do this within libgdx, or do I need to use Android specific code?

```
private void addNameTextEdit() {
    stage = new Stage();
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));

    nameText = new TextField("Last Name", skin);
    nameText.setMaxLength(HighScore.MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
    nameText.selectAll();
    nameText.addListener(new EventListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean handle(Event event) {
            if (event instanceof InputEvent) {

                if (((InputEvent) event).getKeyCode() == Input.Keys.ENTER) {
                    addHighScoreAndSave();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    table = new Table();
    stage.addActor(table);
    table.add(nameText).width(290).height(45);
    stage.setKeyboardFocus(nameText);
    table.setSize(290, 45);
    table.setPosition(20, 400);

    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
    Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(true);
}
```